# How to change the root of <xsl:for-each > dynamically in xslt file

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to change the root of `<xsl:for-each>` dynamically. Actually I used nested loop. Based on the outer loop I want to change the root of inner loop.
For that I write the following code but I am not able to do it.

outer loop start
then
variable that hold root

```
<xsl:variable name="cdtitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/Data/AppNameEncrpt"/>
    </xsl:variable>  
    inner loop
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($cdtitle)">
    ..
    </xsl:for-each>
```

If I pass the static value of `msxsl:node-set($cdtitle)` then it work but when I pass it as a varible in root it not work

How can achieve the same. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Please provide the complete XSLT with the input and expected output. The explanation of the problem isn't clear enough.

Comment: Are you perhaps hoping that the variable cdtitle will hold the expression `"/root/Data/AppNameEncrpt"`, rather than the result of evaluating the expression?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT (as in any functional language), variables are immutable. However, inside a "loop" (which technically is not a loop) you can set the variable to anything that is in the context of that loop. Since you didn't show any input XML, I am guessing to what you want to achieve, but there's always a (simple) way.

Suppose you have this variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="cdtitles" select="/data/cds/title" />
```

It will hold all cd titles. Now I can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$cdtitles">
    <xsl:variable name="cdtitle" select="." />
    <!-- do something with the title, var changes with each title -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Have a look at [XSLT: Getting started](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch01_01.htm), it will help you understand these and other principles of the language.